# Filtering additions to a list

Tags: design, design-patterns, programming-practices, object-oriented-design

Hopefully Iʼm posting this in the right SX, and Iʼve tagged it correctly.

I have a legacy system that Iʼm making additions to which contains a custom list object.

This list object can contain two types of elements, another list, or an item.

Part of a current task requires that I make an adjustment to the list in such a way as to exclude the addition of items or lists dependent on their type or whether they are in another list of a different or the same type.

An array of items can be passed to the list object, and theyʼre added one at a time in a loop.

I would like to implement the rules as to whether an item can be added to a list as a separate business rules class where I pass the list and item to the rule class and receive a Boolean value back as to whether the item can be added to the list or not. Something along the lines of:

```
function InsertItems(ArrayOfItems)
    for each item in ArrayOfItems
        if ruler.CanItemBeAddedToList(item, list) then
            add(item)
        end if
    end for
end function
```

The language used for the legacy system is VB.NET hence the BASIC style of the pseudo-code.

In general terms is it best to have a separate class to hold a rule such as this, or should it be part of the list class or the item class? That said the more I think about it the more I prefer a rule-class to make the decision rather than embedding the decision in the list. I donʼt believe it should be embedded in the item class. Though you can write it nicely e.g.

```
if item.CanBeAddedTo(list) then
   add(item)
end if
```

But this effectively means that the item must know about lists, which is not good from a coupling point-of-view. On the other hand should a list know about items especially given that the list is not a generic one?

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view the method "CanBeAdded" should neither be in the item, nor in a special rulter. It should be in the list itself. Therefore:

```
if list.CanAdd(item)
    ...
end
```

The List implementation then should have a set (probably implemented as list) of rules, that define whether an item can be added.

```
function CanAdd(item) As Boolean
    for each rule in ListOfRules
        if Not(rule.IsFulFilledBy(this, item))
           return False
        end
    end
    return True
end
```

This allows the system to be open to new rules, without having to be changed (Open/Closed-Principle).

I beg to excuse any syntactical mistakes. I am not very familiar with BASIC style languages.